# Rev 22:17 related to Isaiah 55:1

Tags: translation-philosophy

I read on this forum an explanation of the Hebrew idiom in Isaiah 55:1. It referenced an association with Rev 22:17.
Can someone clarify how these two scriptures are associated.

Comment: The related question is [What does Isaiah 55;1 mean ... ?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/19798/what-does-isaiah-551-mean-by-buying-without-money/26536#26536) and the first answer covers this inquiry.

Comment: Check the vs in Rev.  There is no Rev. 17:22.

Comment: Sorry wrong reference in rev, I’ll go back and find it

Comment: It's Revelation 22:17.

Comment: Sorry  the correct reference is Rev 22:17 ty Nigel - how does Isaiah 55:1 relate to the Rev reference

Comment: I’m new to this forum so ty for patience MK

Answer (score 0):

Revelation calls upon much of the OT prophets, and uses many metaphors that the Hebrews understood.  Much of YHWH's word, and especially the prophesies were expressed with metaphors and similes comparing natural objects to spiritual conditions. Man understands that bread is food for the belly, which prolongs carnal life.  God used that metaphor for the true spiritual life to be found in His word.

The parallels of the OT scriptures will define these metaphors, and shine a light on the meanings in the NT, and in Revelation.  Pulling one scripture away from the section in which it appears will remove it from the context.  It is best to keep the scripture within its surroundings to understand the usage and meaning of the words.

Isaiah chapter 55 is a Messianic prophesy for the "covenant-age during" under the gospel of Christ and for the merciful providence of God for all who will come to Him.

> *"Seek ye Jehovah, while He is found, Call ye Him, while He is near, 7 Forsake doth the wicked his way, And the man of iniquity his thoughts, And he returneth to Jehovah, and He pitieth him, And unto our God for He multiplieth to pardon."*  (Isa. 55:6-7, YLT)

Isa. 55:1 basically says the mercies of God are freely given - buy, or acquire without money - meaning His grace costs us nothing. It is ours for the taking. Read Isa. 55:1-3 in the YLT.

> *"Ho, every thirsty one, come ye to the waters, And he who hath no money, Come ye, buy and eat, yea, come, buy Without money and without price, wine and milk.*
>
> *2 Why do ye weigh money for that which is not bread? And your labour for that which is not for satiety? Hearken diligently unto me, and eat good, And your soul doth delight itself in fatness."*
>
> *"3 Incline your ear, and come unto me, Hear, and your soul doth live, And I make for you a covenant age-during, The kind acts of David -- that are stedfast."*

Isa. 55:2 contrasts the food YHWH offers freely with the carnal bread of false doctrine (that which is not bread) purchased with labor and money.

Adam Clarke's Commentary on Isa. 55:1 -

> "Ho, every one that thirsteth - "Water," says Zimchi, "is a metaphor for the law and wisdom: as the world cannot subsist without water, so it is impossible that it can subsist without wisdom. The law is also compared to wine and milk: to wine because wine rejoiceth the heart, as it is written: 'The statutes of the Lord are right, rejoicing the heart,' Psalm 19:8. It is compared also to milk, because milk is the subsistence of the child; so are the words of the law the nourishment of his soul who walks in the Divine teaching, and grows up under it."  Source: [here](https://www.studylight.org/commentaries/acc/isaiah-55.html)

Rev. 22 continues the picture from Rev. 21 of the heavenly Jerusalem and the heavenly temple in the everlasting kingdom of the Messiah which is within all who are in Christ (Luke 17:20-21) under the covenant of the gospel of Christ which Isaiah had prophesied.  It begins with the water of life freely given in vs 1:

> *"And he shewed me a pure river of water of life, bright as crystal, going forth out of the throne of God and of the Lamb: 2 in the midst of its broad place, and of the river on this side and on that, [is] a tree of life, yielding twelve fruits, in each several month rendering its fruits, and the leaves of the tree [are] for the service of the nations;"*  (Rev. 22:1-2, YLT)

And Rev. 22:17 picks it up again, calling all who will come.

> *"17 And the Spirit and the Bride say, Come; and he who is hearing -- let him say, Come; and he who is thirsting -- let him come; and he who is willing -- let him take the water of life freely."*  (YLT)

And the meaning is repeated from Isa. 55, that YHVH's grace, His offer is freely given -buy (take) without money- to all those who will come to Him for the true life under the everlasting covenant - the gospel of Christ.

Comment: Thanks so much for your insight